# How to make the following two figures in a horizontal line？

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C1.5em{
 && g \ar[dl]_{*} \ar[dr]^{*}  &&\\
  & f' \ar[dr]_{*} && h' \ar[dl]^{*} \\
  && f''
}
\
\xymatrix@C1.5em{
 && g \ar[dl]_{} \ar[dr]^{}  &&\\
  & f' \ar[dr]_{*} && h' \ar[dl]^{*} \\
  && f''
}
\end{document}
```

How to make the above two figures in a horizontal line？

Comment: your question is not very clear and your example code can not run on its own without some packages that you have not shown. It looks like xypic but you have tagged the question with tikz ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edit my code. But I don't know how to post the code clearly.

Comment: By "parallel line", do you mean "horizontal line"? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encase each graph in a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
\xymatrix@C1.5em{
 && g \ar[dl]_{*} \ar[dr]^{*}  &&\\
  & f' \ar[dr]_{*} && h' \ar[dl]^{*} \\
  && f''
}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
\xymatrix@C1.5em{
 && g \ar[dl]_{} \ar[dr]^{}  &&\\
  & f' \ar[dr]_{*} && h' \ar[dl]^{*} \\
  && f''
}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I add \usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} \usepackage{tikz-cd} to my paper, but It doesn't run. ! Latex Error: Option clash for pack xy.

Comment: @Daisy - Please note that my answer copied the document setup of your example code one for one. If you're using a different setup in your real document, please do tell us more about it.